# Does best-fit memory allocation always succeed when worst-fit does?

Tags: memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Assuming a particular heap state, if worst fit works for the next allocation than best fit should as well, assuming that the difference is only the order that free space areas are checked, because then the success or failure only depends on whether or not a big enough free space is available. But if you mean for a given sequence of allocations, which change the state in a path dependent way, then there are no guarantees and Lior's tool can help with finding the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this malloc algorithm visualizer:
https://github.com/dmednis/malloc-algorithm-visualizer
you can come up with similar counterexamples to this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL6eS.png